# python 3.5: numpy - how to avoid deprecated technique

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm just starting to teach myself to program in Python and I'm getting a "error" message I don't understand:

```
DeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will  
result in an error in the future  
value_could_be[i0:i1, j0:j1, k] = 0
```

`value_could_be is a 9*9*9 numpy.ndarray` of integers.
`i0, i1, j0, j1, k` are all integers, presumably valid as subscripts as the code works just as I want it to.

```
value_could_be[i, :, k] = 0
```

doesn't generate the same warning

How should I code this to be future proof?

I'm running numpy 1.10.1, python 3.5, spyder 2.3.7, anaconda 2.2.0 (originally installed with python 2.7 and python 3.5 added later). The whole is running under OSX Mountain Lion.

When I Google the message I find references to "theano" but as far as I am aware I'm not using that. Neither do I want to just suppress the message.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `i0`, `i1`, `j0`, `j1`, and `k` are all integers? That message sounds like at least one of those things is actually an array.

Comment: I can reproduce the warning by using an array containing a single integer in a slice, e.g. `np.zeros(10)[:np.array([3])]`

Comment: Sorry, yes - I've printed the values of i0, i1, j0, j1 and it appears that sometimes (but not always) one pair (i0/i1 or j0/j1) are actually one-dimensional arrays eg [1].  How do I convert them to integers?

Comment: To remove brackets you can use `i0=numpy.squeeze(i0)`. Scalars and single-value arrays come out as scalars.

Comment: Converting them to integers is the wrong thing to do. Figure out what bug is causing them to not be integers, and fix that bug.

Comment: Yes @user2357112, working back I find that whilst `np.ravel(np.nonzero(value_could_be[i0:i1, j0:j1, k]))` results in a tuple of 2 scalars, `np.ravel(np.nonzero(value_could_be[i, :, k]))` results in a single-value array - frankly, I don't understand why (or why indexing an array with a single-value array should be depreciated) but putting `np.squeeze(np.nonzero(value_could_be[i, :, k]))` as suggested fixes it.

Comment: Indexing an array with a single-value array isn't deprecated, but it has subtly different behavior from indexing with an int, and it's also not quite what you're doing. "Converting an array to an index" means implicitly interpreting it as an int with `operator.index`. It happens in cases like `[0][numpy.array([0])]` - note that `[0]` is a list here. We don't want that to happen. (In your case, why `operator.index` is getting called is probably due to how NumPy treats the slices.)

Comment: This seems to be a problem for me on one of my Debian Jessie 8.x machines but not on another. I'm using numpy with sklearn and I get this error. However on the other machine I don't get the error. If I pass an array of a list to a tree structure in sklearn it works on one machine whereas I don't work on the other. In the second case it says its deprecated and you need to just pass the list unmodified for the calculation to work. By the way... both machine running the same sklearn, numpy and python versions. Which makes the issue even stranger.