# VisibleDepricationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
test.py:93: VisibleDepricationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future
    self.selected.set_data(refs_cov[dataind], refs_gc[dataind])
```

I get the above error message when using a modified version of this code: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/data_browser.html

**My modified version:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class _PointBrowser(object):

    """
    Click on a point to select and highlight it -- the data that
    generated the point will be shown in the lower axes.  Use the 'n'
    and 'p' keys to browse through the next and previous points
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.lastind = 0

        self.selected, = ax.plot([x[0]], [y[0]], 'o', ms=6, alpha=0.8,
                                 color='red', visible=False)

    def onpick(self, event):

        if event.artist != line:
            return True

        N = len(event.ind)
        if not N:
            return True

        dataind = event.ind

        # Handle error message that exits the program when clicking on an area
        # with nested data points, as that will result in dataind == array of multiple values
        try:
            print 'Reference: %s\nCoverage: %.2f\nGC: %.2f%%\nLength: %d\n' % \
                    (np.take(refs, dataind)[0], np.take(x, dataind), np.take(y, dataind), np.take(refs_lengths, dataind))

        except TypeError:
            pass

        self.lastind = dataind
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.lastind is None:
            return

        dataind = self.lastind

        ax2.cla()
        ax2.plot()

        # Handle error message that exits the program when clicking on an area
        # with nested data points, as that will result in dataind == array of multiple values
        try:
            ax2.text(0.05, 0.9, 'Reference: %s\nCoverage: %.2f\nGC: %.2f%%\nLength: %d\n' % \
                    (np.take(refs, dataind)[0], np.take(x, dataind), np.take(y, dataind), np.take(refs_lengths, dataind)), \
                    transform=ax2.transAxes, va='top')

            self.selected.set_visible(True)
            self.selected.set_data(x[dataind], y[dataind])

        except TypeError:
            ax2.text(0.05, 0.9, 'Error: Try pan/zoom!',
                    transform=ax2.transAxes, va='top')

        fig.canvas.draw()
```

**What I want to achieve:**
A plot where you can pick a value using the mouse, which then lights up that data point with red in ax and prints out specific info about that point in ax2 and in the terminal.

This has been achieved, everything works exactly as expected. Except for the error message. It shows up only the first time I choose a value with the mouse. Even then, it prints out everything as expected.

Anyone have a clue as to why it shows up?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095946/python-3-5-numpy-how-to-avoid-deprecated-technique).

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that event.ind returns an array with ndim == 1. So that `dataind.ndim` returns 1. There seems no other way around it than either converting dataind to an int or using `dataind = self.lastind[0]`

Comment: Update: The workarounds in my above comment led to other errors in my script, so I found a simpler solution by changing only one thing. In `def onpick()` I changed `dataind = event.ind[0]`, whch effectively turns it into `<type 'numpy.int64'>`.